# Ending a Thread in python (also using callbacks)

Tags: python, multithreading, speech-recognition

I was working with speech recognition software and found a way to have the speech recognizer listen indefinitely such that there is a smoother user experience. I have a kickout command that should end the program if the word terminate is ever said. The code is shown below...

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys

def callback(recognizer, audio):                          # this is called from the background thread
    try:
        print("You said " + recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
        if(text == 'Terminate' or  text == 'terminate'):
             sys.exit()
    except:
        pass
r = sr.Recognizer()
r.listen_in_background(sr.Microphone(), callback)
import time
while True: time.sleep(0.1)
```

I have tried setting all the threads to daemon and have tried using Os.exit(). Please let me know if there is any other things I should try.

Comment: Could you provide which library you're using, how other threads are being kicked off, and more specifics on what you want to happen when "terminate" is detected (i.e. should all threads stop what they're doing or should just the main thread exit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** this is untested. I don't have this package installed.

However, just by reading the source code at https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__init__.py I discovered this:

The call `listen_in_background` returns a reference to the `stopper()` function, which terminates the listening thread in an acceptably nice way.  In order to leverage this, try the following:

```
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys

stop_it = False

def callback(recognizer, audio):  # this is called from the background thread
    global stop_it
    try:
        print("You said " + recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
        if text.lower() == 'terminate':
            stop_it = True
    except:
        pass

r = sr.Recognizer()
just_try_and_stop_me = r.listen_in_background(sr.Microphone(), callback)

while True:
    if stop_it:
        just_try_and_stop_me(wait_for_stop=True)
        break
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

**NB:** Globals are kinda hackish, so for your next challenge, try to encapsulate all this in a proper class.  But for now, this should be pretty good for starters. Also, there is no need for parentheses around your condition (this isn't C). Also, `.lower()` method on a string will return the lowercase version for simpler case-insensitive comparisons.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. I just had to add a break statement under the "if stop_it" branch

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I updated my answer to reflect that.